# Is there a better way to get different data from an API in the same component based on data type?

Tags: reactjs

I have a homepage with multiple sections, and I wanted each section to get different data, one for "Popular Recipes" and one for "New Recipes" for example. So I wrote a switch statement inside a useeffect for this but it feels not "the best way" to me.

Home.js:

```
import React from "react";
import { Container } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import Section from "./Section";

const sections = [
  {
    name: "Popular Recipes",
  },
  { name: "New Recipes" },
];

function Home() {
  return (
    <Container maxWidth="full">
      {sections.map((section, i) => (
        <Section key={i} name={section.name} />
      ))}
    </Container>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

Section.js:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Text, Flex, Box, Spacer, SimpleGrid, Heading } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { getAllRecipes } from "../api";
import Recipe from "../common/Recipe";

function Section(props) {
  const [recipes, setRecipes] = useState([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState("");
  useEffect(() => {
    switch (props.name) {
      case "Popular Recipes":
        getAllRecipes()
          .then((data) => {
            setRecipes(data);
          })
          .catch((error) => setError(error.response.data.error));
    }
  }, []);
  return (
    <Box marginBottom="10">
      <Heading as="h2" marginBottom="5" fontSize="xl" fontWeight="hairline">
        {props.name}
      </Heading>
      <SimpleGrid minChildWidth="250px" columns={3} spacing={6}>
        {error ? (
          <Text>{error}</Text>
        ) : (
          recipes?.map((recipe) => {
            return <Recipe key={recipe._id} recipe={recipe} />;
          })
        )}
      </SimpleGrid>
    </Box>
  );
}

export default Section;
```

Comment: It might be better to fetch the different kinds of recipes in the home component and pass only the related data to each Section component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of depending on `props.name`, just have your `Section` component accept a `getRecipes` prop and pass it explicitly in the parent component. This decouples `name` from the actual implementation, so changing from `Latest Recipes` to `Latest Posts` (or whatever) won't break your app.

```js
// queries.js -----

export const getPopularRecipes = () => fetch('/recipes/popular').then(res => res.json());

export const getLatestRecipes = () => fetch('/recipes/latest').then(res => res.json());

// Section.js -----

function Section(props) {
  // ...

  useEffect(() => {
    props.getRecipes()
      .then(data => setRecipes(data))
      .catch(error => setError(error.response.data.error));
  }, []);

  // ...
}

// Home.js -----

import { getPopularRecipes, getLatestRecipes } from './queries';

function Home() {
  return (
    <Container maxWidth="full">
      <Section name="Popular" getRecipes={getPopularRecipes} />
      <Section name="Latest" getRecipes={getLatestRecipes} />
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Alternatively, if the logic for fetching recipes is identical (only the API path is different, for example), you can have the `Section` component accept a `recipeType` prop (or similar).

```js
// Section.js -----

function Section(props) {
  // ...

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`/recipes/${props.recipeType}`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => setRecipes(data))
      .catch(error => setError(error.response.data.error));
  }, []);

  // ...
}

// Home.js -----

import { getPopularRecipes, getLatestRecipes } from './queries';

function Home() {
  return (
    <Container maxWidth="full">
      <Section name="Popular Recipes" recipePath="popular" />
      <Section name="Latest Recipes" recipePath="latest" />
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Either way, decouple your network implementation from your `name` and you should be resilient to future refactors.

Comment: The only problem with these solutions is that if I have 1,000 sections I have to write all of them. I tried to prevent this by looping through an array of section objects and render the section component. Maybe should I add the api function to each of the objects.

Comment: You'll have to specify the value for `getRecipes` or `recipePath` regardless, whether you do it one at a time per `Section` or inside the `sections` object you use in your question. You would just use something like `const sections = [{ name: 'Popular Recipes', recipePath: 'popular' }, { name: 'Latest Recipes', recipePath: 'latest' }, ...]`.